# Can we ALWAYS write a LINQ query (equivalent to a) complex T-SQL query with many joins and complex SQL statements?

Tags: c#, linq, t-sql, c#-4.0, ado.net

The latest technology to access SQL databases from C# is Linq. Before we used ADO.NET with T-SQL queries. My question is: can we ALWAYS build an equivalent Linq query for any complex T-SQL statement (complex large query with many JOINS and statements)?

Do we still need to use old ADO.NET access for large and complex query building?

Comment: From my understanding Ling queries are still ADO.NET under the hood. From that using Linq is adding an additional layer of processing on top. Linq is not about performance, but about abstraction!

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot and should not use LINQ for everything  SQL can do. For ex. PIVOT, UNPIVOT GROUPING, ROLLUP, CUBE. Also, Kindly let complicated query writing be handled by tool meant for that (complex sql query in SQL server). That way, your code and database as well will remain maintainable.